# How to cache videos from API in Swift and retrieve/play them?

Tags: swift, xcode, caching, video

I have searched the internet far and wide to try and find a video caching solution with Swift. Nothing seems to work, and there aren't any good third party libraries out there that i can make work either.

I am building a TikTok style app and storing my videos in Firebase, and every time the video shows it downloads the video data, which is terrible for performance and database usage.

Here's my code and what im doing. It seems that i can write video data to disk storage, but my problem is retrieving that file url and using it to play a video with an `AVPlayer`

Cache Manager class

```
class CacheManager {
    static let shared = CacheManager()
    private let fileManager = FileManager.default

    private var mainDirectoryUrl: URL {
        let documentsUrl = self.fileManager.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        return documentsUrl
    }

    func getFileWith(stringUrl: String) async throws -> URL {
        let file = directoryFor(stringUrl: stringUrl)

        guard !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: file.path) else { return file }
        
        do {
            guard let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: stringUrl)!) else { throw URLError(.unknown) }
            videoData.write(to: file, atomically: true)
            return file
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }

    private func directoryFor(stringUrl: String) -> URL {
        let fileURL = URL(string: stringUrl)!.lastPathComponent
        let file = self.mainDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileURL)
        return file
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
func playVideo() {
  Task {
     let testVideoUrlString = "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4"
            
      do {
           let fileUrl = try await CacheManager.shared.getFileWith(stringUrl: testVideoUrlString)
           print("DEBUG: File url is \(fileUrl)")
           let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUrl.standardizedFileURL.absoluteString)
           player.replaceCurrentItem(with: .init(url: url))
       } catch {
           print("DEBUG: Fallback to videoUrl. Cache failed with error: \(error)")
           guard let url = URL(string: testVideoUrlString) else { return }
           player.replaceCurrentItem(with: .init(url: url))
       }
   }
}
```

The print statement gives me back this:
`file:///Users/[username]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9D7CE00B-AF1D-4E61-B293-19678E6BC9E8/data/Containers/Data/Application/0B76C033-8E6C-4F21-B75D-01B4078F26EC/Library/Caches/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4`

Trying to use that URL to play a video just leaves me with a blank black screen. Anyone have any idea on what to do here? Or why it isn't working?